Prove that $\operatorname{dim\,range}(TS) \leq 2.$
Here is the question I am thinking about:
Suppose $\operatorname{dim} V = 5$ and $S,T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ are such that $ST = 0.$ Prove that $\operatorname{dim\,range}(TS) \leq 2.$
Here are my thoughts:
Since $ST = 0,$ then $\operatorname{null} ST = V,$ and hence
$\operatorname{dim\,null}(ST) = \operatorname{dim} V = 5.$ But then,  we know that $$ 5 = \operatorname{dim\,null} ST \leq \operatorname{dim\,null} S + \operatorname{dim\,null} T \quad \quad (1)$$
But by $FTLM,$ we know that $$ \operatorname{dim} V = 5 = \operatorname{dim\,null} S + \operatorname{dim\,range} S = \operatorname{dim\,null} T + \operatorname{dim\,range} T   \quad \quad (2)$$
Therefore, from $(2),$ we know that
$$\operatorname{dim\,null} S + \operatorname{dim\,range} S + \operatorname{dim\,null} T + \operatorname{dim\,range} T = 10 \quad \quad (3)$$ Hence, $$\operatorname{dim\,range} S + \operatorname{dim\,range} T = 10 - (\operatorname{dim\,null} S +\operatorname{dim\,null} T)  \leq 5 \quad \quad (4)$$
where the last I equality in $(4)$ comes from $(1)$
But then I can use the following inequality (without proof):
$$\operatorname{dim range} ST \leq \operatorname{min}(\operatorname{dim range} S, \operatorname{dim range} T )$$
I do not know how to get the number 2 required in the problem then, can anyone clarify this to me please?

Do you mean by $"\mathbf {null } S"$ the kernel of $S$? i.e. the pre image of 0?

After (1), you can conclude that one of the null spaces has dim at least $3$, i.e., one of $S,T$ has rank at most $2$

why is that ? @HagenvonEitzen

Since $ST=0$, you must have $\text{null }S\supseteq \text{range }T$ and thus, $$\dim \text{null }S\geq\dim \text{range }T$$
Using rank-nullity theorem, you have $\dim \text{null }S=5-\dim \text{range } S$.
$$\therefore 5\geq  \dim \text{range }T + \dim \text{range }S$$
This means that either $\dim \text{range }T$ or, $\dim \text{range }S$ is strictly less than $3$ for otherwise, their sum will exceed $5$.
The claim follows using  $\text{rank }AB\leq \min\{\text{rank }A,\text{rank }B\}$. $\blacksquare$
